# Schengen Visa four years- 90 days stay

Tags: visas, schengen

I have been granted multiple entry Schengen Visa valid for 4 years with the duration of stay of 90 days. Does it mean only 90 days of stay in total during a 4 years period?

I'll be travelling to Schengen Area in September for 25 days, then after 2 month or so I will travel again for 30 days. Similarly, I'll be traveling to the Schengen Area in the future depending on the business meetings.

How will I know, that how many days are left? On what basis the calculations are done?  Also, please explain the "90/180" rule.

Comment: During these 4 years, in any period of 180 days, you cannot stay for longer than 90 days.

Comment: @gdrt that's an answer; can you source it and post it as such?

Comment: For those voting to close: the proposed duplicate does not include enough information for the asker of this question to know that the 90/180 rule applies to the described visa.

Comment: I have reopened this question for the reason described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any visa valid longer than six months, the duration of stay will be 90 days, but it means that the bearer of the visa may be present in the Schengen area subject to the 90/180 day rule.  In other words, your visa authorizes you to be in the Schengen area for up to 90 days in any 180-day period, subject to some additional conditions.

This is explicit in the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412):

> When a visa is valid for more than six months, the duration of stays is 90 days in any 180-day period.

This text is found at the end of item four of Annex VII.  The annex describes the rules for filing out the visa sticker, and item four concerns the "duration of stay" element.  For reference, and in support of the assertion that all visas valid for longer than six months will have a 90-day duration of stay, here's all of point four:

> 4.   ‘DURATION OF VISIT ... DAYS’ heading:
>
> This heading indicates the number of days during which the visa holder may stay in the territory for which the visa is valid. This stay may be continuous or, depending on the number of days authorised, spread over several periods between the dates mentioned under 2, bearing in mind the number of entries authorised under 3.
>
> The number of days authorised is written in the blank space between ‘DURATION OF VISIT’ and ‘DAYS’, in the form of two digits, the first of which is a zero if the number of days is less than 10.
>
> The maximum number of days that may be entered under this heading is 90.
>
> When a visa is valid for more than six months, the duration of stays is 90 days in any 180-day period.